# Type annotation for classmethod returning instance

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

How should I annotate a `@classmethod` that returns an instance of `cls`? Here's a bad example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar: str):
        self.bar = bar

    @classmethod
    def with_stuff_appended(cls, bar: str) -> ???:
        return cls(bar + "stuff")
```

This returns a `Foo` but more accurately returns whichever subclass of `Foo` this is called on, so annotating with `-> "Foo"` wouldn't be good enough.

Comment: `-> 'Foo'` is correct, that's all you can (or should) be enforcing about the return value.

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#precise-typing-of-alternative-constructors

Comment: As `typing.Self` has been introduced with Python 3.11 through [PEP-0673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), the [second example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71118499/) may be referenced (i.e. `-> Self:`) instead if no backward compatibility is required.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The trick is to explicitly add an annotation to the `cls` parameter, in combination with `TypeVar`, for [generics](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html), and `Type`, to [represent a class rather than the instance itself](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects), like so:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

# Create a generic variable that can be 'Parent', or any subclass.
T = TypeVar('T', bound='Parent')

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, bar: str) -> None:
        self.bar = bar

    @classmethod
    def with_stuff_appended(cls: Type[T], bar: str) -> T:
        # We annotate 'cls' with a typevar so that we can
        # type our return type more precisely
        return cls(bar + "stuff")

class Child(Parent):
    # If you're going to redefine __init__, make sure it
    # has a signature that's compatible with the Parent's __init__,
    # since mypy currently doesn't check for that.

    def child_only(self) -> int:
        return 3

# Mypy correctly infers that p is of type 'Parent',
# and c is of type 'Child'.
p = Parent.with_stuff_appended("10")
c = Child.with_stuff_appended("20")

# We can verify this ourself by using the special 'reveal_type'
# function. Be sure to delete these lines before running your
# code -- this function is something only mypy understands
# (it's meant to help with debugging your types).
reveal_type(p)  # Revealed type is 'test.Parent*'
reveal_type(c)  # Revealed type is 'test.Child*'

# So, these all typecheck
print(p.bar)
print(c.bar)
print(c.child_only())
```

Normally, you can leave `cls` (and `self`) unannotated, but if you need to refer to the specific subclass, you can add an [explicit annotation](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self). Note that this feature is still experimental and may be buggy in some cases. You may also need to use the latest version of mypy cloned from Github, rather then what's available on pypi -- I don't remember if that version supports this feature for classmethods.

Comment: @taway -- huh, cool! I could have sworn it didn't, but I'm glad to hear that I'm wrong!

Comment: What if I want with_stuff_appended to return an instance of Child?

Comment: IMHO, Python with type checking can be compared with Rust in complexity, and time to market. But `mypy`  saved me many times, so it is definitely a must-have tool.

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs type annotations are optional

Comment: Great answer!  It might be worth mentioning [PEP 673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/) when it's accepted.

Comment: do you know how this works if Parent is a generic class? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72327987/2828064

Comment: I don't like the way Python does this.  I like so much about the language, but when it comes to OOP, there are too many special cases.  Why does `TypeVar` need strings for its arguments?  Using strings in places where symbols should be used is one of the more annoying things in Python.

Answer (score 67):

Just for completeness, in Python 3.7 you can use the `postponed evaluation of annotations` as defined in [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) by importing `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning of the file.

Then for your code it'd look like

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar: str):
        self.bar = bar

    @classmethod
    def with_stuff_appended(cls, bar: str) -> Foo:
        return cls(bar + "stuff")
```

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html), this import will effectively be automatic starting with Python 3.11.

Comment: Looks like a nasty surprise to me. If I say `-> Foo`, than I expect this function to return an object of type `Foo`, not a subclass.

Comment: @SebastianWagner I'm a bit lost with the comment, my answer doesn't address that but only on how to make the annotation nicer in current Python.

Comment: @SebastianWagner There is no surprise. Why are you confusing  by thinking of a subclass?

Comment: Because if you subclass Foo, then the classmethod will return subclass, not Foo, but the type definition says Foo.

Comment: @MaikuMori This looks very natural to me. An instance of a subclass is also an instance of the class. You can experiment this with `isinstance`. This corresponds to basic stuff taught in OO classes that you can use a parent class reference to refer to a child class instance.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP question. Returning the correct type each time is needed if some method is present only in the subclass and not the parent class. I'm sure lots of people knew how to use postponed annotations and still ended on this thread and benefited from @Michael0x2a answer (That was my case)

Comment: @xuhdev It may look natural to you, but it is wrong.  While you're right that it should is returning a `Foo`, the caller will usually want the return type to be narrower in the calling code.

Comment: I understand using this technique is probably not the ideal approach, but I'm annoyed with the `TypeVar` solution.  I will use this technique in my code for now only because it is a small, one-off application and I don't plan to subclass any of the classes contained therein.

Answer (score 10):

**Python version >= 3.11**: Since Python 3.11, you can now use [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) to avoid declaring a `TypeVar`. It can be used with `@classmethod`, [as specified in PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures):

> The `Self` type annotation is also useful for classmethods that return an instance of the class that they operate on. For example, `from_config` in the following snippet builds a `Shape` object from a given config [...]
>
> ```
> from typing import Self
>
> class Shape:
>     @classmethod
>     def from_config(cls, config: dict[str, float]) -> Self:
>         return cls(config["scale"])
> ```

This correctly handles subclassing, as required by the question:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    pass

Circle.from_config(config)  # mypy says this is a Circle
```

Comment: Here `cls` still has its type inferred - if I want this, I would write `cls: type[Self]`, but then mypy complains: `Method cannot have explicit self annotation and Self type`. Is this a shortcoming in mypy or something wrong with it? QUICK EDIT: Just realized that Mypy has issue with `cls: type[Self]` but not `cls: Type[Self]`. Interesting.

Comment: @jonaslb doing `cls: typing.Type[Self]` instead is compatible with mypy, however it's deprecated since 3.9. I'm not sure why mypy complains. I'm also not sure why you would want to annotate `cls` instead of the class method's return value.

Comment: Oh, I would not get rid of the return type. It's just about proper annotation for the `cls` argument. I know it's inferred by Mypy, so it's not strictly necessary to put it, but nevertheless I think it would be a relevant point to include for this question.

Comment: For compatibility with Python <3.11, you can using `typing_extensions.Self` in [`typing_extensions`](https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).