# Why does Type[T] -> T classmethod fail in Unsupported type when the bound of T has an optional argument?

Tags: python, class, type-hinting, mypy

I love python's type hints, and I wrote the following script, which fails with `Unsupported type Type["T"]` in MyPy 0.590.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

AnyT = TypeVar('AnyT')
T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')


class A:
    def __init__(self, arg: AnyT = None) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls: Type[T]) -> T:  # E: Unsupported type Type["T"]
         return cls()
```

Why this causes an error?

In typical use case, `AnyT` equals to `T` and `__init__(self, other)` copies the `other` to `self`.

Note that following slightly different programs have no errors:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')


class A:
    def __init__(self, arg: int = None) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls: Type[T]) -> T:  # No errors
         return cls()
```

and

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

AnyT = TypeVar('AnyT')
T = TypeVar('T')  # no bounds


class A:
    def __init__(self, arg: AnyT = None) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls: Type[T]) -> T:  # No errors
         return cls()
```

And also note that the following solution does not work for me:

```
from typing import TypeVar

AnyT = TypeVar('AnyT')


class A:
    def __init__(self, arg: AnyT = None) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> 'A':  # Obviously no errors
         return cls()
```

That is because this does not consider the inheritance of `A` (if a class `B` inherits from `A`, `B.fn()` will return the instance of `B`, but MyPy thinks it returns that of `A` in this example).

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant mypy issue: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/254

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/44640479/5951320

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this was a bug in mypy because it no longer occurs.

The return type of a class method can now be written more easily using the [`Self` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) (introduced in Python 3.11 but available in earlier versions through the [`typing_extensions` package](https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```py
    @classmethod
    def fn(cls) -> Self:
         return cls()
```

The original snippet now causes an unrelated mypy error in the `__init__()` function: "`error: Incompatible default for argument "arg" (default has type "None", argument has type "AnyT")`" while pyright says "`error: TypeVar "AnyT" appears only once in generic function signature`".