# Python: type-hinting a classmethod that returns an instance of the class, for a class that is inherited

Tags: python, mypy, typing

Consider the following:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("A")
        self.hello = "hello"

    # how do I type this so that the return type is A for A.bobo()
    # and B for B.bobo()?
    @classmethod
    def bobo(cls) -> UnknownType:
        return cls()


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        print("B")
        super().__init__()
        self.world = "world"


instance_of_B = B.bobo()  # prints "B", then "A", and returns an instance of B
```

I want to type-hint the `bobo` class method, so that mypy can know that in the case of `B`'s `bobo` method, it's not just an instance of `A` that's returned, but actually an instance of `B`. I'm really unclear on how to do that, or if it's even possible. I thought that something like `Type[cls]` might do the trick, but I'm not sure if that even makes syntactic sense to mypy.

Comment: What happens if you do use `Type[cls]`?

Comment: playground2.py:48: error: Name 'cls' is not defined      
playground2.py:51: error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "Type[Any]")     
playground2.py:62: error: Argument 1 to "bobo" of "A" has incompatible type "A"; expected "Type[Any]"

Comment: `cls` is the name of the parameter, not the *type* of that parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type annotation for classmethod returning instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640479/type-annotation-for-classmethod-returning-instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use a `TypeVar`, thankfully, in Python 3.11 the `typing.Self` type is coming out. [This PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/) describes it in detail. It also specifies how to use the `TypeVar` until then.

Comment: This answer would be substantially improved by explaining *how* to use a `TypeVar`.  Right now, it's just an allusion to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, the classmethod section in that link explained how to solve my issue very well. Good to know they're planning to make it a more intuitive and legible syntax !

Answer (score 22):

For an example of how to apply Brian's answer:

- with a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```py
from typing import TypeVar


AnyA = TypeVar("AnyA", bound="A")


class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("A")
        self.hello = "hello"

    @classmethod
    def bobo(cls: type[AnyA]) -> AnyA:
        return cls()

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        print("B")
        super().__init__()
        self.world = "world"

reveal_type(B.bobo())  # B
```

- with `Self`:

```py
from typing import Self

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print("A")
        self.hello = "hello"

    @classmethod
    def bobo(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        print("B")
        super().__init__()
        self.world = "world"

reveal_type(B.bobo())  # B
```

If your version of Python doesn't have `Self` yet, you can use the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package, which serves as backport for some typing features:

```
- from typing import Self
+ from typing_extensions import Self
```