# mypy: How to declare the return type of a method returning self in a generic class?

Tags: generics, mypy, python-typing

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644576/2828064) does not seem to work for generics. Mypy complains about "error: Missing type parameters for generic type A" when checking the following code. I have tried using `'A[T]'` for the TypeVar but then mypy says "error: Type variable T is unbound." I have also tried using `AnyA[T]` as return type of `get` but that produces two error messages, the already known "error: Missing type parameters for generic type A" and the new error message "Type variable AnyA used with arguments".

How do I specify the return type of `get` correctly?

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
AnyA = typing.TypeVar('AnyA', bound='A')

class A(typing.Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def get(self: AnyA) -> AnyA:
        return self

class B(A[T]):
    def is_int(self) -> bool:
        return isinstance(self.val, int)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B(42)
    print(b.get().is_int())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know of three ways of typing here:

#### Declaring an inner self-type

This approach is described in `mypy` docs, see [Precise typing of alternative constructors](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#precise-typing-of-alternative-constructors).

```python
class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    _Self = typing.TypeVar('_Self', bound='A[T]')

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def get(self: _Self) -> _Self:
        return self
```

Note however, that this is `mypy`-specific stuff and may not work with other checkers. E.g. `pyre` doesn't support inner self-types yet.

#### Using `_typeshed.Self`

This saves the boilerplate of declaring custom types, but requires a somewhat obscure import from typeshed which will fail at runtime. It thus must be wrapped by `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`:

```python
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import Self
else:
    Self = Any

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def get(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self
```

`_typeshed.Self` was created to be used in custom stubs in the first place, but is suitable for inline typing as well.

#### Python 3.11 and upwards: `typing.Self`

A recently introduced [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) adds `Self` to stdlib, so starting from Python 3.11 one will be able to use that:

```python
from typing import Self

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def get(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self
```

This is not supported by `mypy` yet as of now though, but e.g. by `pyright` from version 1.1.184.

Comment: It does not look like one can add a type to typing.Self, one should be able to write types like typing.Self[int] per vscode (pyright)

Comment: @spacether yes, `typing.Self` is not subscriptable. This is deliberate, [as stated in PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes): _Note that we reject using `Self` with type arguments, such as `Self[int]`. This is because it creates ambiguity about the type of the self parameter and introduces unnecessary complexity. [...] In such cases, we recommend using an explicit type for `self`._