# Mypy 'Self' type narrowing for inherited `__init__`

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy, typing, type-narrowing

I'm trying to bring together typing class attributes via generic types pointing at the current instance and inheritance. I ran into a problem that mypy seems to fail in narrowing down generic types bound by the class at creation to the same type as the current `self`. I want to know if it's a bug or misunderstanding on my side.

Before we start:

- python version: 3.10.6
- mypy version: 0.991

---

Consider a simple scenario of implementing a `Node` of a tree structure.

Naturally, such a node should have `parent` and `children` attributes.
These can be optional. But, when they are not `None`, they should be of the same class as `Node`.

Let me illustrate that below:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections import abc


class Node:
    def __init__(
        self, parent: Node | None = None, children: abc.Sequence[Node] | None = None
    ):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
```

Now, if we are to inherit from `Node` without changing the `__init__`'s signature, we'd run into trouble: type of children doesn't reflect the inheritance:

```py
from typing_extensions import reveal_type


class SpecialNode(Node):
    ...


sn = SpecialNode()
reveal_type(sn.children)  # Union[Sequence[Node], None]
```

The correct way out (until [PEP-673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) is supported, see [#11871](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11871)) should be using generic types bound by `Node` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72329557) for instance):

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar('T', bound='Node')


class Node:
    def __init__(
        self: T, parent: T | None = None, children: abc.Sequence[T] | None = None
    ):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
```

However, inheriting from this class doesn't narrow the type `T` down to the subclass for the attributes:

```py
sn = SpecialNode()
reveal_type(sn.children)  # Union[Sequence[T`-1], None]
```

(It's not really clear to me at the moment what `-1` stands for, but I assume `T` is still a type variable bound by `Node`)

The problem here is that if we were to use `sn.children` in a function accepting `Sequence[SpecialNode]`, mypy would not see `` Sequence[T`-1] `` as an equivalent type and treat this attempt as an error.

```py
def fn(xs: abc.Sequence[SpecialNode]) -> None:
    ...


if sn.children is not None:
    fn(sn.children)  # Argument 1 has incompatible type "Sequence[T]"
```

**What I would want instead is for `sn.children` to have the type `Union[Sequence[SpecialNode], None]` or a type variable `TypeVar('S', bound=SpecialNode)`.**

One could also attempt to manually narrow down the `T` type to the current instance's type:

```py
def is_type(x: t.Any, _type: t.Type[T]) -> t.TypeGuard[T]:
    return isinstance(x, _type)


def is_seq_of(s: abc.Sequence[t.Any], _type: t.Type[T]) -> t.TypeGuard[abc.Sequence[T]]:
    return all(isinstance(x, _type) for x in s)


class Node:
    def __init__(
        self: T, parent: T | None = None, children: abc.Sequence[T] | None = None
    ):
        assert parent is None or is_type(parent, self.__class__)
        assert children is None or is_seq_of(children, self.__class__)
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children

        reveal_type(self.parent)  # Union[T`-1, None]
        reveal_type(self.children)  # Union[Sequence[T`-1], None`]


sn = SpecialNode()
reveal_type(sn.children)  # Union[Sequence[T`-1], None]
```

However, the revealed type is still `` Union[Sequence[T`-1], None] ``; hence the type narrowing didn't work out.

Comment: Also I'd propose to make `children` always a `Sequence` (never None), because now you have both `[]` and `None` available to represent no children, and there should be one - and preferably only one - way...

Comment: `typing.Self` already works on `mypy` master branch - when 1.0 is released (hope it'l happen soon), you can use it safely.

Comment: If you're in hurry, you can construct same thing as [PEP673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-attribute-annotations) (last example in linked section) mentions as current solution for attribute annotations: switch to properties that wrap untyped/Any private members (or typed + cast).

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks. PEP673 explicitly states that the `Self` type is equivalent to annotating the `self` attribute with a `_Self = t.TypeVar("_Self", bound="Node")`. Consequently, the problem will likely persist even when it's officially supported. I guess we'll find out soon enough.

As for the suggested solution of switching to properties, could you please elaborate on that? I'm not sure I'm on the same page. Thanks.

Comment: No, the problem doesn't happen with normal `Self`, here's [a playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=cdafe523f901f687dc3052201082b76a). This equivalence is not this strict, when you have different scopes (your `T` **is** bound in `__init__`, but makes no sense in instance attribute annotation, since `T` isn't bound  to the instance, check [this issue by me](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14343) inspired by this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin with sane solution, that uses master branch of `mypy` where `Self` is already supported (it will be added in v 1.0 release).

```py
from collections import abc
import sys

# You may omit this guard and pick the import for your version;
# typing_extensions import will be valid forever, 
# but stl is preferrable in general
if sys.version_info < (3, 11):
    from typing_extensions import Self
else:
    from typing import Self

class Node:
    def __init__(
        self, parent: Self | None = None, children: abc.Sequence[Self] | None = None
    ):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children
        
class SpecialNode(Node):
    ...


sn = SpecialNode()
reveal_type(sn.children)  # N: Revealed type is "Union[typing.Sequence[__main__.SpecialNode], None]"
```

Here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=cdafe523f901f687dc3052201082b76a) for this.

However, `Self` type is not **strictly** necessary. Your example fails, because `T` is bound only in `__init__`, but ends up in attribute annotation, being completely pointless. Check [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14343) (inspired by your question, though I've seen much simpler cases of the same problem on SO) for some context. You can write an ugly workaround. This shows that `mypy` actually has some knowledge about `_parent` and `_children` attributes (because we don't cast), but doesn't expose it without rain dances.

```py
from collections import abc
import typing as t

_Self = t.TypeVar('_Self', bound='Node')


class Node:
    # Here we require that constructr arguments are really of proper type, 
    # but hide _Self under properties later
    def __init__(
        self: _Self, parent: _Self | None = None, children: abc.Sequence[_Self] | None = None
    ):
        self._parent = parent
        self._children = children
        
    @property
    def parent(self: _Self) -> _Self | None:
        return self._parent
    
    @parent.setter
    def parent(self: _Self, parent: _Self | None) -> None:
        self._parent = parent
    
    @parent.deletter
    def parent(self) -> None:
        del self._parent
        
    @property
    def children(self: _Self) -> abc.Sequence[_Self] | None:
        return self._children
    
    @children.setter
    def children(self: _Self, children: abc.Sequence[_Self] | None) -> None:
        self._children = children
    
    @children.deletter
    def children(self) -> None:
        del self._children
        


class SpecialNode(Node):
    ...


sn = SpecialNode()
reveal_type(sn.children)  # N: Revealed type is "Union[typing.Sequence[__main__.SpecialNode], None]"
reveal_type(sn.parent)  # N: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.SpecialNode, None]"
sn.parent = SpecialNode()
sn.children = []
sn.parent = Node()  # E: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Node", variable has type "Optional[SpecialNode]")  [assignment]
sn.children = [Node()]  # E: List item 0 has incompatible type "Node"; expected "SpecialNode"  [list-item]
```

Here's [playground link for this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=8acc80f10085dd26ceb164e54e6cb58b).

Bonus: if you still have an opportunity to adjust the API, do it, please. There should be one - and preferably only one - way to do something. In your case `children = []` and `children = None` means essentially the same - no children. If it doesn't make real difference (e.g. None meaning "not set yet"), then non-optional sequence would be saner.

Also (again, if mutating original list/set is not intended), I'd use `children` setter anyway to accept any `abc.Iterable[_Self]` and convert it to a list or tuple in setter - but this will kill `mypy`, unfortunately (**very** annoying [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3004) with unsupported asymmetric properties).

Comment: Your elaboration on `T` being bound to `__init__` exposed my misunderstanding of how generics work. To be entirely sure, in your example, does binding `_Self` to a `self` in a property narrow down the type to the type of the current instance?

Comment: Regarding the "Bonus" section, I'd use `self.children = children or []` in `__init__`. I just wanted to keep things simple. But the suggestion is a good general practice for sure, so thanks.

Comment: Annotating `self` with `_Self` does exactly this: for the scope of current function, `_Self` is resolved to type of `self` (which is certainly known). The problem with non-generic class is that it does never leave the scope of one function, be it `__init__` or anything else, so `_Self` as annotation of instance attribute makes no sense.

Comment: typing_extensions will return the ones from the stdlib if they exist, so importing from there without the check will end up with the exact same Self.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling yes, but this guard looks better IMO: this way I can drop `typing_extension`, when the project upgrades `python`, and in toy examples this basically means "if you use modern enough python, then `typing_extensions` dependency is unnecessary".