# How to specify the type of a callable python dataclass member to accept subclass instances

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I would like to be able to specify a data class member that is callable and takes the instance of the derived class. If I was using abstract member functions this would be easy.

I've tried code like the following but don't know what argument to provide for the Callable type specification. I am looking for a way to annotate the `handler` attribute such that derived classes can take instances of themselves as the argument to `handler` (`Specific` in this case) not just `Base`.

```python
@dc.dataclass
class Base():
    name: str
    handler: typing.Callable[['Base'], str] # <--- What to use instead of 'Base'


@dc.dataclass
class Specific(Base):
    specific: str


# This is the callable that I would like to use.
def specific_handler(v: Specific) -> str:
    return f"{v.specific}"

# Assigning specific_handler to handler gives a type error.
sg = Specific(name="two", handler=specific_handler, specific="extra info")

# The handler can be used in following manner.
assert("extra info" == sg.handler(sg))
```

I am using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While answer by @dROOOze works, it is unnecessary verbose (requires repeating the class name as a generic attribute). The alternative solution below uses [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) (added on python 3.11 via [PEP673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), backported via `typing_extensions`, supported on `mypy` master - though 0.991 still lacks this feature). So, if you can use master `mypy` branch or read this answer later, then `mypy 1.0` and above fully supports `Self`.

Here's a [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=449d6ceb5958ecb3c758b07ce95529cb).

```py
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable
# You can omit this guard for specific target version
if sys.version_info < (3, 11):
    from typing_extensions import Self
else:
    from typing import Self


@dataclass
class Base:
    name: str
    handler: Callable[[Self], str]

@dataclass
class Specific(Base):
    specific: str

def specific_handler(v: Specific) -> str:
    return f"{v.specific}"


sg = Specific(name="two", handler=specific_handler, specific="extra info")
assert "extra info" == sg.handler(sg)
```

Comment: Maybe i misinterpreted the question, but I thought they wanted `handler` to have an arbitrary subclass of `Base` and to be annotated on `Base`. The interpretation you’re proposing doesn’t require `typing.Self`, they could annotate it as `self.handler: …` on a dataclass `__post_init__` method instead.

Comment: @dROOOze Yes, `__post_init__` solution could work, but it doesn't in fact (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74915504/mypy-self-type-narrowing-for-inherited-init/74919129#74919129)), if I understand your proposal properly. I understand the question as "how to annotate `handler` that should take self type", though your answer is the only right under another interpretation, I see it now.

Comment: You are correct that the question was basically asking how to annotate `handler` such that it should take self. I had an implementation working with abstract member functions and wanted to use callable attributes instead. I will update the question to make this detail clear.

Answer (score 2):

The solution still involves `typing.TypeVar`.

As long as `handler`'s first parameter does not accept an argument of the same type as the owning class, then `Base` must be generic (if it *is* of the same type, you can get away with using `typing.Self`). It doesn't really matter if the first parameter of `handler` is a subclass of `Base`, that is just a detail you add to `typing.TypeVar(bound=...)`.

```py
import dataclasses as dc
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound="Base[typing.Any]")

@dc.dataclass
class Base(typing.Generic[T]):
    name: str
    handler: typing.Callable[[T], str]

# `Base["Specific"]` assumes that you want `Specific.handler` to be of type `typing.Callable[[Specific], str]`, which is true in this situation.
# Otherwise just provide another subclass of `Base` (or `typing.Any`).
@dc.dataclass
class Specific(Base["Specific"]):
    specific: str

def specific_handler(v: Specific) -> str:
    return f"{v.specific}"

sg = Specific(name="two", handler=specific_handler, specific="extra info")
assert "extra info" == sg.handler(sg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dROOOze. This does work but is a little too generic for my needs - sorry that the question wasn't clear enough. I have updated the question to be (hopefully) more specific.